VHDL if statement precedence
So, this code was given to me to fix, and it made me wonder how it actually should work. The key pitfall here is multiple IF statements in a process that sets/clears the same output. So which one "wins"?
Example:
IF(A = 0) THEN
  C <= '0';
END IF;

IF (B = 2) THEN
 C <= '1';
END IF;


Edit: fixed wrong output name.
So what will happen if A is 0 and B is 2 ??? Will the last IF take precedence??
And where in the VHDL spec is this precedence defined ?
The simulator showed that the first one wins, but I'm not sure it is correct

First, B and b are the same object, so something is lost in your example.   Assuming that 'b' is a separate name, then the last executed assignment wins.   This would be better written as an if - then -elsif with the check for B = 2 first - as most understand what should happen there.

Signal updates are scheduled in a projected output waveform (a queue). "If the after clause of a waveform element is not present, then an implicit “after 0 ns” is assumed." (10.5.2.2  Executing a simple assignment statement -2008, -2019) for the incremental delay from the current simulation time, potentially causing a delta cycle. The rules for operating the queue for a signal driver insure there's only one entry a specific simulation time. Here the assignments are sequential and the last one wins. Synthesized hardware will reflect the implicit priority of the two.

If '0' and '1' are valid values for signal b (or B, VHDL is not case sensiitve), then 2 is not. The main issue here is inconsistency the b typing. Once you will have fixed this, the behavior will be: last assignment wins.

As some pointed out the output should have been named anything but b (or a). The code shown was made up based on countless of examples in the real code, but I was a bit to hasty

@LarsMathisson So, why don't you fix your question? And while you're at it, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Fixed the naming confusing. There is no point in a full example. The question was about VHDL procedure precedence, and that has been answered several times now.

@LarsMathisson There is a point in a full example because you claim that "The simulator showed that the first one wins, but I'm not sure it is correct" which is impossible with a LRM-compliant simulator. So, please edit your question and add a full example that exhibits the behavior you claim such that we can reproduce it and investigate. You could also visit the help center and especially the asking section to better understand how this website works.

My question has been answered. If you feel you have additional questions feel free to post a new thread. I have posted the code that is essential to the question and the problem have been resolved

And others who are in doubt about the precedence of IF statements will find the answer here. And that was the question hence the title and the question text.  This was backed up my a minimal example that everyone but you figured out and answered. I must admit I find your behavior rather rude.

VHDL LRM 11.3, Process statement defines:

"A process statement defines an independent sequential process representing the behavior of some portion of the design"

with:
process_statement_part ::=
 { sequential_statement }

...

sequential_statement ::= [§ 10.1]
 wait_statement
 | assertion_statement
 | report_statement
 | signal_assignment_statement
 | variable_assignment_statement
 | procedure_call_statement
 | if_statement
 | case_statement
 | loop_statement
 | next_statement
 | exit_statement
 | return_statement
 | null_statement

so all statements in a process are sequential. A process will either execute once when a signal in the sensitivity list has a 'event or the process will execute as a loop until it hits a wait statement. All code executed within this period occurs within the same delta cycle, and hence if multiple assignments to a signal occur, the last one is the one that will be scheduled to be assigned at the end of the delta cycle, as it will override all previous assignments.
VHDL LRM 10.5.2.2 Executing simple assignment statement (under 10.5 Signal Assignment Statements):

The sequence of transactions is then used to update the projected
output waveform representing the current and future values of the
driver associated with the simple waveform assignment statement.
Updating a projected output waveform consists of the deletion of zero
or more previously computed transactions (called old transactions)
from the projected output waveform and the addition of the new
transactions, as  follows:
a) All old transactions that are projected to occur at or after the
time at which the earliest new transaction is projected to occur are
deleted from the projected output waveform.
b) The new transactions are then appended to the projected output
waveform in the order of their projected occurrence.

So in your case, assuming the code you posted is executed in the same delta cycle, with A=0 and B=2, then b will end up being '1'. If this is not the case, then:

Some form of user error, either with the code posted or reading the waveform
The Simulator has a bug.

I highly doubt 2 is the case as this is pretty fundamental mechanism of VHDL that has been like this since VHDL 1987. If you still are still not seeing this, then I suggest you post a complete MCVE so that we can diagnose what the problem is.

Thanks for the reply. That was what I was looking for. I assume having the two statements inside a rising_edge clause does not change anything regarding precedence.

An if rising_edge then inside a process is just another layer of if statement.
